# How to correctly extract records from this table?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, t-sql, linq-to-sql

I have an associative table with a **DATE** field:

```
|       DATE          |  USER_ID  | GROUP_ID   |
| 2012-09-20 00:00:00 |     7     |     1      |
| 2012-09-20 00:00:00 |     6     |     1      |
| 2012-09-13 00:00:00 |     5     |     1      |
| 2012-09-10 00:00:00 |     1     |     1      |
| 2012-09-02 00:00:00 |     5     |     3      |
| 2012-08-02 00:00:00 |     5     |     2      |
| 2012-07-01 00:00:00 |     5     |     1      |
| 2012-07-01 00:00:00 |     3     |     1      |
```

Each record represents an association between a user and a group.
Each association is valid from the date indicated in the table and remains constant until a new association is inserted in the table.

To know user-group association for a certain date is pretty easy: just select the maximum date <= than indicated date.

But now **I need to extract all users associated with a certain group in a range of dates**.
The provided parameters are: **group_id**, **date_from**, **date_to**.

I have to implement this with Linq, but I'm trying to test the procedure using T-SQL.

That's what I've tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_group
where group_id = 1
and '2012-09-11' <= date
and date <= '2012-09-20'
UNION
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM user_group
where group_id = 1
and date <= '2012-09-11'
order by date desc
```

but obviously it doesn't work...

**NOTE:**

the main difficulty is to get associations created before the **from_date** but still valid. For clarity, I need to get this result:

```
|       DATE          |  USER_ID  | GROUP_ID   |
| 2012-09-20 00:00:00 |     7     |     1      |
| 2012-09-20 00:00:00 |     6     |     1      |
| 2012-09-13 00:00:00 |     5     |     1      |
| 2012-09-10 00:00:00 |     1     |     1      |
| 2012-07-01 00:00:00 |     3     |     1      |
```

Comment: @CuongLe 2012-07-01 must be included in the result because user 3 is still associated to group 1

Comment: for the sql how about `Select MAX(Date), [USER_ID] from Test where [Group_ID] = 1 Group By [User]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found this solution, that works for me:

```
var innerAssoc = from assoc in user_group
                 where assoc.group_id == group_id
                 && dateFrom.Date <= assoc.date.Date
                 && date.Date <= dateTo.Date
                 select assoc;

var outerAssoc = from assoc in user_group
                 where assoc.group_id == group_id
                 && assoc.date.Date == user_group
                 .Where(a => a.user_id == assoc.user_id && a.date.Date <= dateFrom.Date)
                 .Select(a => a.date.Date).Max()
                 select assoc;

var res = innerAssoc.Union(outerAssoc);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from user_group where group_id=1 and date<=convert(date,'2012-09-20',120)
except
select * from user_group where group_id=1 and date<=convert(date,'2012-09-11',120)
```

Or perhaps this...

```
select date, user_id, group_id
from
(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by user_id order by date desc) rn 
    from user_group
    where date<=convert(date,'2012-09-20',120)
) v
where rn=1
and group_id=1    
order by date desc
```

Comment: I think this is not correct, because using this I cannont get all the association created before 2012-09-11, but still valid...

Comment: @davioooh It would help to know what results you want? - See above edit?